Coq proving special cases of the law of the exlcuded middle: equalities on inductive types
I recently tried to prove that $x = y \lor x \neq y$ for two types $\mathbb{N}$ and $\text{Option}[\mathbb{N}]$.
The first special case is easy to prove with lia, but for the second I ended up proving it in an absurd way by mapping $\text{Option}[\mathbb{N}]$ into $\mathbb{N}$.
Anyway, there has to be an easier way to prove this. What is it? Even the lia proof is very long for what it does and contains unnecessary references to specially-encoded natural numbers.
(* option_nat.v *)
From Coq Require Import Lia.

Lemma nat_lem : forall x y : nat, x = y \/ x <> y.
Proof. lia. Qed.

Fixpoint option_nat_to_nat x :=
  match x with
  | None => O
  | Some x => S x
  end.

Fixpoint nat_to_option_nat x :=
  match x with
  | O => None
  | S x => Some x
  end.

Lemma option_nat_to_nat_simplifies : forall x, x = option_nat_to_nat (nat_to_option_nat x).
Proof. induction x; now simpl. Qed.

Lemma nat_to_option_nat_simplifies : forall x, x = nat_to_option_nat (option_nat_to_nat x).
Proof. induction x; now simpl. Qed.

Lemma leibniz : forall {T} {U} (f : T -> U) a b, a = b -> f a = f b.
Proof.
  intros T U f a b I.
  now rewrite I.
Qed.

Lemma contrapositive : forall A B, (A -> B) -> (not B -> not A).
Proof.
  intuition.
Qed.

Lemma leibniz_contrapositive : forall {T} {U} (f : T -> U) a b, f a <> f b -> a <> b.
Proof.
  intros T U.
  pose proof @leibniz T U.
  pose proof contrapositive.
  now intuition.
Qed.

Lemma option_nat_lem : forall x y : option nat, x = y \/ x <> y.
Proof.
  intros x y.
  set (x' := option_nat_to_nat x).
  set (y' := option_nat_to_nat y).
  pose proof nat_lem x' y'.
  destruct H.
  - enough (x = y).
    + firstorder.
    + unfold x' in *.
      unfold y' in *.
      assert (nat_to_option_nat (option_nat_to_nat x) = nat_to_option_nat (option_nat_to_nat y)) by firstorder.
      pose proof nat_to_option_nat_simplifies x.
      pose proof nat_to_option_nat_simplifies y.
      rewrite <- H1 in *.
      now rewrite <- H2 in *.
  - unfold x' in *.
    unfold y' in *.
    pose proof (leibniz_contrapositive option_nat_to_nat x y) H.
    now intuition.
Qed.


You should prove something more general: if a has decidable equality, then so does option a.

If not interested in tunning the decision algorithm, there is a tactic called decide equality that works for simple inductive types, like eg list (option nat * bool).

It is done the same way you would program a function deciding the equality.
For option nat this is done by case analysis and relying on the decidability of nat:
Require  Import Arith.
Lemma option_nat_lem : forall x y : option nat, x = y \/ x <> y.
Proof.
  destruct x as [n|];destruct y as [m|].
  - destruct (Nat.eq_decidable n m) as [heq|hneq];subst.
    + left;reflexivity.
    + right.
      intro abs.
      apply hneq.
      inversion abs.
      reflexivity.
  - right.
    intro abs.
    inversion abs.
  - right.
    intro abs.
    inversion abs.
  - left;reflexivity.
Qed.

On nat that would be done by induction and case analysis:
(* We would decide equality this way by a functino:
Fixpoint decnat (x y:nat)  {struct x} : bool :=
  match x with
    0 => match y with
         | 0 => true
         | _ => false
         end
| S n => match y with
         | 0 => false
         | S m => decnat n m
         end
  end.
*)

Lemma nat_lem : forall x y : nat, x = y \/ x <> y.
Proof.
  induction x; destruct y.
  - left;reflexivity.
  - right.
    intro abs.
    inversion abs.
  - right.
    intro abs.
    inversion abs.
  - destruct (IHx y).
    + subst;left;reflexivity.
    + right.
      intro abs.
      inversion abs.
      contradiction.
Qed.


Maybe even go for + in place for \/?
